# R Generic References to Data Frames and Variables

Tags: r, generics

I would like to know how to make a reference to a data frame and variable generic, please. Say I have a data frame named 's' and a variable in that data frame named 'Y'.

Regular R code:

```
look = s$Y
```

What I would like to do:

```
data = s

variable = Y

look = data$variable (which functions the same as look = s$Y)
```

Any thoughts? The reason I would like to do this is that I have `s$Y` throughout my code, and later I may want to change `s` for `t` (or `Y` for some other variable), and don't want to have to go through all of my code manually replacing `s$Y` with `t$Y` where I need it changed.

Thanks!

Comment: Write a function.  You've already got your parameters. `f <- function(data, variable) data[[variable]]; f(t, "Y")`  but it's just as easy to do `var <- "Y"; t[[var]]`

Comment: Or just use `data` and `variable` but assign them like your first two lines at the top of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit duckmayr. This is my first question.

Comment: Thanks, Rich. I have already used a function and data[[variable]]. I searched high and low for a way to do 'look = data$variable'. Maybe there is no way?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the reason that the `$`-operator is considered poor-practice inside function definitions, i.e. it "locks you in" to a particular spelling of a column name. You are not going to do this, however:

```
variable = Y
```

Rather you are going to do this:

```
variable = "Y"
```

And that is because the first version would have caused the R-interpreter to go out and try to identify a value for the symbol `Y` someplace in what is known as its "search path" which is roughly speaking all that functions and values that have been called and are still being processed since code was started. In the case of the second version "Y" is its own value and no further searching is needed. With that fundamental confusion corrected you would now do this

```
look <- data[[ variable ]]  # although using 'data' as a name is another "poor-practice"
```

Whereupon R will look for a value of `variable` and find it in the global environment, returning the character "Y" and delivering a column named "Y" from the dataset `s`. Column names are not considered first-class objects in R, whereas named dataframes are. The "names" of columns are not true R `names` (even though they are called `colnames`).. The `$`-operator is just shorthand for "[[" with a character value. Here's a full transcript to test this:

```
> s <- data.frame(Y=1:10, X=LETTERS[1:10]); data = s
> 
> variable <- "Y"
> 
> look1 <- data$Y; look2 <- data[["Y"]]
> identical(look1, look2)
[1] TRUE
```

The confusion that this "non-standard evaluation" (NSE) shorthand feature of R has caused new users appears to be one of the motivations for the creation of first the ggplot `aes` function and later the evolution of the package-`dplyr` and the `tidyverse`-bundle-of-packages. Those packages allow the use of non-quoted names or tokens to refer to column identities.

Comment: Great reply, thank you! I had come across 'data[[variable]]' but I couldn't figure out how to make 'data' (the data frame) generic. I got as far as 'as.name('s$Y')' but when I code 'test = as.name('s$Y')' and 'look = test' it returns 's$Y'. And yes, I know I shouldn't use 'data' as name! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @42-'s answer, you can dynamically reference columns like this:

```
colName <- "something"
myDataFrame[,colname]
```

Edit: Since you also asked about dynamically referencing data.frames @Rich Scriven suggested making a function that takes the data.frame as an argument, which is one working solution.  You can also just load the data you need at the top of your script, which is easy to change on the fly if you need:

```
fileName <- "file1.csv"
data <- read.table(fileName, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's starting to look that data$variable is not possible and I should use a function. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As per -42 above, the best choice seems to be the packages referenced. Using a function is close but doesn't seem to allow 'data' and 'variable' to be generic in 'data$variable'.

Thanks everyone!